# Add custom telemetry properties inside Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function (v2) where data is passed in as JSON via the HTTP body. I want to log some of this JSON data in Application Insights, using the standard *Trace* and *Request* events.

What I've tried so far:

- Use a custom `ITelemetryInitializer` which parses the body and adds properties to `ISupportProperties.Properties`. This has 2 disadvantages though: the body is read and parsed multiple times for each request (once in my Function, and multiple times in the telemetry initializer), and sometimes accessing the body throws an exception because it has been disposed (probably it goes out of scope at the end of the Function call).
- Use an `TelemetryClient` inside my Function. But this client doesn't seem to have an appropriate property to set:

  - `TelemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties` is meant for global properties, and not for request-scoped properties;
  - `TelemetryClient.Context.Properties` is obsolete, and I don't see how I can use the recommended replacement `ISupportProperties.Properties` there.

Ideally I want to use the data which is parsed inside my Function, and use that data to initialize the telemetry data.

Comment: Young could just write trace logs with [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#write-logs-in-c-functions). Also you could log [custom telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions).

Comment: @GeorgeChen My goal is to enrich the default Trace and Request log messages which are written to Application Insights, not to write extra log messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can update request telemetry properties by adding tags on `Activity.Current` like  `Activity.Current?.AddTag("my-prop", ExtractPropFromRequest());`  Without any additional changes, these tags will appear on requests.  Unfortunately, you won't get them stamped on traces.
2. You can also parse your request body once in the function and store it in AsyncLocal. Then access this AsyncLocal in the TelemetryInitializer

```cs
 public class AsyncLocalPropertyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
 {
   public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
     {
       if (telemetry is ISupportProperties propTelemetry &&
           Function1.AdditionalContext.Value != null) // you may find a better way to make it work with DI
         {
           propTelemetry.Properties["my-prop"] = Function1.AdditionalContext.Value;
         }
      }
  }


public static class Function
{
    internal static readonly AsyncLocal<string> AdditionalContext = new AsyncLocal<string>();
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
      AdditionalContext.Value = "something important"; // read the body here
      log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.") 
      AdditionalContext.Value = null;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion with `Activity.Current` is working and is something I can use.
But the second suggestion is not working for me. At the moment `ITelemetryInitializer.Initialize` is called for normal request, the AsyncLocal field no longer has a value. So apparently the telemetry initializer is called from withing a different context.

Comment: I can't get #1 to work.. I don't see the Tags in the customDimensions -- does #1 work for Azure Functions v1 compiled to .NET Framework ?

Comment: This seems to have been taken from here. I'm guessing the author is the same on both https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1428#issuecomment-509491535