# How to set parent id and operation id of the telemetry in Azure Application Insights for Azure function using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-sdk

I have an function app: funct1(HttpTrigger) -> blob storage -> func2(BlobTrigger). In Application Insights, there will be two separate request telemetry generated with different `operation id`. Each has its own end-to-end transaction trace.

In order to get the end-to-end trace for the whole app, I would like to correlate two functions by setting the `parent id` and `operation id` of func2 with `request id` and `operation id` of func1 so both can be shown in application insights as one end-to-end trace.

I have tried following code but it didn't take any effect and there is a lack of documentation about how to use application insights Java SDK in general for customizing telemetry.

```
@FunctionName("Create-Thumbnail")
@StorageAccount(Config.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)
@BlobOutput(name = "$return", path = "output/{name}")
public byte[] generateThumbnail(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "blob", path = "input/{name}")
                byte[] content,
        final ExecutionContext context
) {
    try {

        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();
        TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        client.getContext().getOperation().setParentId("MY_CUSTOM_PARENT_ID");
        client.flush();

        return Converter.createThumbnail(content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Anyone with knowledge in this area can provide some tips?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851912/add-custom-telemetry-properties-inside-azure-function

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu this is .net example. The java sdk is quite different. Do you have idea about how to do it in Java sdk?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it can't be achieved as the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-data) said :

> In C# and JavaScript, you can use an Application Insights SDK to write
> custom telemetry data.

If you need to set custom telemetry, you need to add app insights java SDK to your function, but I haven't found any SDK... If there's any progress, I'll update here.

Comment: Yeah. I have seen this documentation and had the same conclusion. Thanks!

Comment: @codigube Many thanks for your reply, if you can pick my post as the answer, I'll appreciate you a lot. Hh, but it's really a pity for no sdk for java function.

Comment: hi, I gave an upvote but will keep this open in case someone else has a different view or solution.

Comment: You're so kind sir. By the way, could you pls delete the question you raised before which is related to this one? You see that if this question be answered, that one will also finish. Thanks in advance : )

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu What Op needs is sdk for azure function -- java, but not sdk for java web app. Thanks for your effort : )

Comment: Do we have any solution to this now, if any please share I am also struggling to find solution to this

Comment: still no update for me